# MapStruct - mapping method from iterable to non-iterable

Tags: spring, dto, mapstruct, iterable

I have been working with MapStruct some days now and haven't yet achieved what i need.

As part of the exercises with Spring, I am writing a small app that will display information about the movies (title, description, director, etc.) and additionally the movie category.
Therefore, I created an additional Entity called Category, so that (e.g. an admin) could add or remove individual category names.

**Movie Entity**:

```
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String director;
    private int year;
    @ManyToMany
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private List<Category> category;
    private LocalDate createdAt;
}
```

**Category Entity**

```
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String categoryName;
    private LocalDate createdAt;
}
```

I packed it all into MapStruct and DTOs.

**MovieDTORequest.java**

```
public class MovieDTORequest {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String director;
    private List<Category> category;
    private int year;
}
```

**MovieDTOResponse.java**

```
public class MovieDTOResponse {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String director;
    private String categoryName; 
    private int year;
    private LocalDate createdAt;
}
```

And **MovieMapper.java**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MovieMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "categoryName", source = "category")
    MovieDTOResponse movieToMovieDTO(Movie movie);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "title")
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", constant = "")
    Movie movieRequestToMovie(MovieDTORequest request);

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "title")
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", constant = "")
    void updateMovie(MovieDTORequest request, @MappingTarget Movie target);

    String map(List<Category> value);
}
```

However, I have a problem with Mapper. First, I got the **error**:

```
"Can't map property "List<Category> category" to "String categoryName". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "String map(List<Category> value)"
```

and when I wrote it in Mapper, I have one more **error**:

```
Can't generate mapping method from iterable type from java stdlib to non-iterable type.
```

I am asking for help, because I am already lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define [default](https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java) implementation for `String map(List<Category> value)` inside `MovieMapper` interface, what would Mapstruct use to map property `List<Category> category` to `String categoryName`. For example:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MovieMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "categoryName", source = "category")
    MovieDTOResponse movieToMovieDTO(Movie movie);

    default String map(List<Category> value){
        //TODO: Implement your own logic that determines categoryName
        return "Movie Categories";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but there is one more thing. The app is starting, but when I want to check the response in Postman I get the **error**:
`IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`
I put 4 categories in Category Entity in my db.

Comment: You should put your own logic there. IndexOutOfBoundException is thrown because the category list of the given movie is empty. I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: You obviously have an issue with persisting those categories in the database.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help. **It works** perfectly with Your previous version when all the movies have categories - `return value.get(0).getCategoryName();`  
  
One more question - is it possible to show more than one category? I have tried with streams etc. but it was not working.

Comment: Great to hear that. The simplest solution would be to make `categoryName` a list of strings, let's say `List<String> categoryNames`. In that case, you would have to change the default method to return `List<String>` and change body to: `return value.stream().map(Category::getCategoryName).collect(Collectors.toList());`.  As result, you would get a list of all category names in the MovieDTOResponse object.